# NPM build task to create zip folder

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install

I am new to npm. I have a one folder which include images and I wanted to have this folder to be zipped in another destination folder.
So if we run 'npm build' it also perform zipping of this folder.
I cannot use gulp or grunt and 'npm pack' is not clear to me

A little help is much appreciated

Comment: Can you expand on what you're doing?

Comment: I haven't done anything but I need to zip one specific folder through npm build

Comment: Can you try this command: `npm run build`

Comment: Also you can use `ng build --prod`

Comment: Okay with this?

Comment: These are the basics commands dear to run project and I am talking about zipping a folder